# JVM How does the Loading process works?

Tags: jvm, loading

I've been trying to understand this part but I there is always some confusion. Okay so I know that there are 3 processes. Loading, Linking and the last one is Initialization of the variables.

So now Suppose that in the main method I call static method of a class. Now this class is passed to the JVM converted to bytecode in a .class file and after that I know information about this class is being outputed(*method names, sub-classes, parent classes etc..*) which stuff can be accessed as the `getClass()` method returns reference. The question here is: Where does it come from? Is it from the Java Object class or from somewhere else? Also is this information being written in the same bytecode `.class` file?

After that there are Class Loaders (*Bootstrap, Extension, Application and User-Defined class loader*). Now what does happen here?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where does *what* come from? And “Now what does happen here?” is not a real question.